# Bash script if condition

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand a piece of code here and as I am not an expert on bash, I am struggling to find out what the below **if** does:

```
  if [[ "$4" == *"-a "* ]]; then
```

I understand the $4 is the fourth parameter, but I am not getting the rest...

Why the condition is between *?

Thank you folks, appreciate any help.

Regards,

Thiago

Comment: shouldn't it be ${4} instead of $4 ? also, i believe in a bash script you only need one pair of [ and ] ...

Answer (score 0):

`[[` is a shell keyword:

```
$ type [[
[[ is a shell keyword
```

so it's described in `help [[` where it says:

```
When the `==' and `!=' operators are used, the string to the right of
the operator is used as a pattern and pattern matching is performed.
```

and in `man bash` under `Pattern Matching` it says:

```
*

Matches any string, including the null string.
```